# How does gmail signature work?

Tags: html, css, gmail

This is pretty much a curiosity question.

Yesterday I created a new signature for Gmail, using HTML.

The code was pretty basic (tables and inline CSS) but then when it came to the point to actually add it to Gmail, the code was not rendering and it was printed as words instead.

After a bit of googling, I realized that to be able to display HTML content on Gmail signature, I have to copy the result from a web page and then paste it into the textbox so that it would work, and actually...it does.

Now, I just wonder why this?

I mean, why copying the result from web page works while pasting the HTML code itself doesn't?

Thanks

Comment: It can be rich text editor, I guess. Paste code in [rich text editor](https://html-online.com/editor/) it will also print code as gmail does.

Comment: If I paste the code in richtext editor, I got back the same html code. If I then paste this in the signature, it's not converted but it still displayed as text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gmail uses a rich text editor that has its own code that runs when you paste into it.  Most people don't use HTML and so Google hasn't implemented the ability to write HTML into it.  They do this to prevent problems with people adding symbols like < > and & into their signatures that would cause issues if parsed as HTML.

If you put the HTML into a website first and then copy it, you are actually copying and pasting the output of the HTML rather than the actual code.  Google is set up to handle pasting formatted content which is why this approach works differently.